# Spring 5.0.3 RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Not sure if this is a bug with Spring 5.0.3 or a new feature to fix things on my end.

After the upgrade, I am getting this error. Interestingly this error is only on my local machine. Same code on test environment with HTTPS protocol works fine.

Continuing...

The reason I am getting this error is because my URL for loading the resultant JSP page is `/location/thisPage.jsp`. Evaluating code `request.getRequestURI()` gives me result `/WEB-INF/somelocation//location/thisPage.jsp`. If I fix URL of JSP page to this `location/thisPage.jsp`, things work fine.

So my question is, should I remove `/` from `JSP` path in code because that's what is required going forward. Or `Spring` has introduced a bug as the only difference between my machine and test environment is protocol `HTTP` versus `HTTPS`.

```
 org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636757/2172731

Comment: Issue is planned to be resolved in 5.1.0; Currently 5.0.0 does not have this issue.

Answer (score 106):

[Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching) mentions the reason for blocking // in the request.

> For example, it could contain path-traversal sequences (like /../) or multiple forward slashes (//) which could also cause pattern-matches to fail. Some containers normalize these out before performing the servlet mapping, but others don’t. To protect against issues like these, FilterChainProxy uses an HttpFirewall strategy to check and wrap the request. Un-normalized requests are automatically rejected by default, and path parameters and duplicate slashes are removed for matching purposes.

So there are two possible solutions -

1. remove double slash (preferred approach)
2. Allow // in Spring Security by customizing the StrictHttpFirewall using the below code.

**Step 1**
Create custom firewall that allows slash in URL.

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);    
    return firewall;
}
```

**Step 2** And then configure this bean in websecurity

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    super.configure(web);
    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
....
}
```

Step 2 is an optional step, Spring Boot just needs a bean to be declared of type `HttpFirewall` and it will auto-configure it in filter chain.

**Spring Security 5.4 Update**

In Spring security 5.4 and above (Spring Boot >= 2.4.0), we can get rid of too many logs complaining about the request rejected by creating the below bean.

```
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.HttpStatusRequestRejectedHandler;

@Bean
RequestRejectedHandler requestRejectedHandler() {
   return new HttpStatusRequestRejectedHandler();
}
```

Comment: Yes path-traversal security has been introduced. Thats a new feature and this could have caused the issue. Which I am not too sure as you see it works on HTTPS and not on HTTP. I would rather wait until this bug is resolved https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16419

Comment: very possibly part of our issue... but... the user isn't typing in a // so I'm trying to figure out how that second / is getting added in the first place... if spring is generating our jstl url it should't add that, or normalize it after adding it.

Comment: This does not actually solve the solution, at least for Spring Security 5.1.1. You have to use DefaultHttpFirewall if you need URLs with two slashes like a/b//c. The isNormalized method cannot be configured or overridden in StrictHttpFirewall.

Comment: Any chance someone could give pointers on how to do this in Spring alone as opposed to Boot?

Comment: In my case an app was distributed with two //. Solve with  firewall.getEncodedUrlBlacklist().remove("//");
After release an update I will remove.

Answer (score 32):

`setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true)` didn't work for me. Still internal method `isNormalized` return `false` when having double slash.

I replaced `StrictHttpFirewall` with `DefaultHttpFirewall` by having the following code only:

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall defaultHttpFirewall() {
    return new DefaultHttpFirewall();
}
```

Working well for me.
Any risk by using `DefaultHttpFirewall`?

Comment: Yes. Just because you cannot create a spare key for your roommate, does not mean you should place the only key under doormat. Not advised. Security should not be changed.

Comment: @java_dude Great how you provided no info or rationale at all, just a vague analogy.

Comment: Another option is to subclass `StrictHttpFirewall` to give a bit more control over the rejection of URLs, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792347/2074605).

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to add this in my bean XML: `<sec:http-firewall ref="defaultHttpFirewall"/>`

Comment: What the implications of using this solution?

Comment: There's also a 
`setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(boolean allowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash)` which should work, instead of switching to `DefaultHttpFirewall`.

Comment: @lainatnavi no because as mentioned in the answer. > Still internal method `isNormalized` return `false` when having double slash.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same problem with:

> Spring Boot version = 1.5.10
>   Spring Security version = 4.2.4

The problem occurred on the endpoints, where the `ModelAndView` viewName was defined with a preceding *forward slash*. Example:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/your-view-here");
```

If I removed the slash it worked fine. Example:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("your-view-here");
```

I also did some tests with *RedirectView* and it seemed to work with a preceding forward slash.

Comment: Thats not the solution. What if this was a bug on Spring side. If they change it, then you will have to undo all the change again. I would rather wait until 5.1 as its marked to be resolved by then.

Comment: No you don’t have to revert the change because defining viewName without preceding forward slash works fine on older versions.

Comment: Thats exactly is what the problem is. If it worked fine and you did not change anything then Spring has introduced a bug. Path should always start with "/". Checkout any spring documentation. Check these out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5007 & https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5044

Comment: This bit me too. Updating all the ModelAndView without the leading '/' fixed the problem

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16740 I opened a bug, but removing the leading / hasn't been a fix for me, and in most cases we're just returning the view name as a string (from the controller). Need to look at redirect view as a solution.

Comment: @xenoterracide Perhaps it's unable to locate your views properly. Where are they located?

Edit: if you use viewResolver.setPrefix("jsp/"); it still doesn't work?

Comment: ours are located in `/jsp/` directory. I think we found a solution to the problem that involves changing our web.xml. Will be updating the ticket.

Answer (score 8):

Once I used double slash while calling the API then I got the same error.

I had to call http://localhost:8080/getSomething but I did Like http://localhost:8080//getSomething. I resolved it by removing extra slash.

Comment: can we write some exception handling for this so that we can tell the notify the client about his wrong input?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, upgraded from spring-securiy-web 3.1.3 to 4.2.12, the `defaultHttpFirewall` was changed from `DefaultHttpFirewall` to `StrictHttpFirewall` by default.
So just define it in XML configuration like below:

```
<bean id="defaultHttpFirewall" class="org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall"/>
<sec:http-firewall ref="defaultHttpFirewall"/>
```

set `HTTPFirewall` as `DefaultHttpFirewall`

Comment: Please add some description to your code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 3):

Below solution is a clean work around.It does not compromises security because we are using same strict firewall.

The Steps for fixing is as below:

**STEP 1 :** Create a Class overriding **StrictHttpFirewall** as below.

```
package com.biz.brains.project.security.firewall;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.HttpFirewall;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException;

public class CustomStrictHttpFirewall implements HttpFirewall {
    private static final Set<String> ALLOW_ANY_HTTP_METHOD = Collections.unmodifiableSet(Collections.emptySet());

    private static final String ENCODED_PERCENT = "%25";

    private static final String PERCENT = "%";

    private static final List<String> FORBIDDEN_ENCODED_PERIOD = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("%2e", "%2E"));

    private static final List<String> FORBIDDEN_SEMICOLON = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(";", "%3b", "%3B"));

    private static final List<String> FORBIDDEN_FORWARDSLASH = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("%2f", "%2F"));

    private static final List<String> FORBIDDEN_BACKSLASH = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("\\", "%5c", "%5C"));

    private Set<String> encodedUrlBlacklist = new HashSet<String>();

    private Set<String> decodedUrlBlacklist = new HashSet<String>();

    private Set<String> allowedHttpMethods = createDefaultAllowedHttpMethods();

    public CustomStrictHttpFirewall() {
        urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_SEMICOLON);
        urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_FORWARDSLASH);
        urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_BACKSLASH);

        this.encodedUrlBlacklist.add(ENCODED_PERCENT);
        this.encodedUrlBlacklist.addAll(FORBIDDEN_ENCODED_PERIOD);
        this.decodedUrlBlacklist.add(PERCENT);
    }

    public void setUnsafeAllowAnyHttpMethod(boolean unsafeAllowAnyHttpMethod) {
        this.allowedHttpMethods = unsafeAllowAnyHttpMethod ? ALLOW_ANY_HTTP_METHOD : createDefaultAllowedHttpMethods();
    }

    public void setAllowedHttpMethods(Collection<String> allowedHttpMethods) {
        if (allowedHttpMethods == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("allowedHttpMethods cannot be null");
        }
        if (allowedHttpMethods == ALLOW_ANY_HTTP_METHOD) {
            this.allowedHttpMethods = ALLOW_ANY_HTTP_METHOD;
        } else {
            this.allowedHttpMethods = new HashSet<>(allowedHttpMethods);
        }
    }

    public void setAllowSemicolon(boolean allowSemicolon) {
        if (allowSemicolon) {
            urlBlacklistsRemoveAll(FORBIDDEN_SEMICOLON);
        } else {
            urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_SEMICOLON);
        }
    }

    public void setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(boolean allowUrlEncodedSlash) {
        if (allowUrlEncodedSlash) {
            urlBlacklistsRemoveAll(FORBIDDEN_FORWARDSLASH);
        } else {
            urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_FORWARDSLASH);
        }
    }

    public void setAllowUrlEncodedPeriod(boolean allowUrlEncodedPeriod) {
        if (allowUrlEncodedPeriod) {
            this.encodedUrlBlacklist.removeAll(FORBIDDEN_ENCODED_PERIOD);
        } else {
            this.encodedUrlBlacklist.addAll(FORBIDDEN_ENCODED_PERIOD);
        }
    }

    public void setAllowBackSlash(boolean allowBackSlash) {
        if (allowBackSlash) {
            urlBlacklistsRemoveAll(FORBIDDEN_BACKSLASH);
        } else {
            urlBlacklistsAddAll(FORBIDDEN_BACKSLASH);
        }
    }

    public void setAllowUrlEncodedPercent(boolean allowUrlEncodedPercent) {
        if (allowUrlEncodedPercent) {
            this.encodedUrlBlacklist.remove(ENCODED_PERCENT);
            this.decodedUrlBlacklist.remove(PERCENT);
        } else {
            this.encodedUrlBlacklist.add(ENCODED_PERCENT);
            this.decodedUrlBlacklist.add(PERCENT);
        }
    }

    private void urlBlacklistsAddAll(Collection<String> values) {
        this.encodedUrlBlacklist.addAll(values);
        this.decodedUrlBlacklist.addAll(values);
    }

    private void urlBlacklistsRemoveAll(Collection<String> values) {
        this.encodedUrlBlacklist.removeAll(values);
        this.decodedUrlBlacklist.removeAll(values);
    }

    @Override
    public FirewalledRequest getFirewalledRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws RequestRejectedException {
        rejectForbiddenHttpMethod(request);
        rejectedBlacklistedUrls(request);

        if (!isNormalized(request)) {
            request.setAttribute("isNormalized", new RequestRejectedException("The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized."));
        }

        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (!containsOnlyPrintableAsciiCharacters(requestUri)) {
            request.setAttribute("isNormalized",  new RequestRejectedException("The requestURI was rejected because it can only contain printable ASCII characters."));
        }
        return new FirewalledRequest(request) {
            @Override
            public void reset() {
            }
        };
    }

    private void rejectForbiddenHttpMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.allowedHttpMethods == ALLOW_ANY_HTTP_METHOD) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this.allowedHttpMethods.contains(request.getMethod())) {
            request.setAttribute("isNormalized",  new RequestRejectedException("The request was rejected because the HTTP method \"" +
                    request.getMethod() +
                    "\" was not included within the whitelist " +
                    this.allowedHttpMethods));
        }
    }

    private void rejectedBlacklistedUrls(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (String forbidden : this.encodedUrlBlacklist) {
            if (encodedUrlContains(request, forbidden)) {
                request.setAttribute("isNormalized",  new RequestRejectedException("The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \"" + forbidden + "\""));
            }
        }
        for (String forbidden : this.decodedUrlBlacklist) {
            if (decodedUrlContains(request, forbidden)) {
                request.setAttribute("isNormalized",  new RequestRejectedException("The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String \"" + forbidden + "\""));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public HttpServletResponse getFirewalledResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new FirewalledResponse(response);
    }

    private static Set<String> createDefaultAllowedHttpMethods() {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        result.add(HttpMethod.DELETE.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.GET.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.HEAD.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.PATCH.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.POST.name());
        result.add(HttpMethod.PUT.name());
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isNormalized(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (!isNormalized(request.getRequestURI())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isNormalized(request.getContextPath())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isNormalized(request.getServletPath())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isNormalized(request.getPathInfo())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean encodedUrlContains(HttpServletRequest request, String value) {
        if (valueContains(request.getContextPath(), value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return valueContains(request.getRequestURI(), value);
    }

    private static boolean decodedUrlContains(HttpServletRequest request, String value) {
        if (valueContains(request.getServletPath(), value)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (valueContains(request.getPathInfo(), value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean containsOnlyPrintableAsciiCharacters(String uri) {
        int length = uri.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = uri.charAt(i);
            if (c < '\u0020' || c > '\u007e') {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean valueContains(String value, String contains) {
        return value != null && value.contains(contains);
    }

    private static boolean isNormalized(String path) {
        if (path == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (path.indexOf("//") > -1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int j = path.length(); j > 0;) {
            int i = path.lastIndexOf('/', j - 1);
            int gap = j - i;

            if (gap == 2 && path.charAt(i + 1) == '.') {
                // ".", "/./" or "/."
                return false;
            } else if (gap == 3 && path.charAt(i + 1) == '.' && path.charAt(i + 2) == '.') {
                return false;
            }

            j = i;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

**STEP 2 :** Create a **FirewalledResponse** class

```
package com.biz.brains.project.security.firewall;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

class FirewalledResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private static final Pattern CR_OR_LF = Pattern.compile("\\r|\\n");
    private static final String LOCATION_HEADER = "Location";
    private static final String SET_COOKIE_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";

    public FirewalledResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
        // TODO: implement pluggable validation, instead of simple blacklisting.
        // SEC-1790. Prevent redirects containing CRLF
        validateCrlf(LOCATION_HEADER, location);
        super.sendRedirect(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
        validateCrlf(name, value);
        super.setHeader(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        validateCrlf(name, value);
        super.addHeader(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        if (cookie != null) {
            validateCrlf(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, cookie.getName());
            validateCrlf(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, cookie.getValue());
            validateCrlf(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, cookie.getPath());
            validateCrlf(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, cookie.getDomain());
            validateCrlf(SET_COOKIE_HEADER, cookie.getComment());
        }
        super.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    void validateCrlf(String name, String value) {
        if (hasCrlf(name) || hasCrlf(value)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid characters (CR/LF) in header " + name);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCrlf(String value) {
        return value != null && CR_OR_LF.matcher(value).find();
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:** Create a custom Filter to suppress the **RejectedException**

```
package com.biz.brains.project.security.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestRejectedExceptionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            try {
                RequestRejectedException requestRejectedException=(RequestRejectedException) servletRequest.getAttribute("isNormalized");
                if(Objects.nonNull(requestRejectedException)) {
                    throw requestRejectedException;
                }else {
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                }
            } catch (RequestRejectedException requestRejectedException) {
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
                log
                    .error(
                            "request_rejected: remote={}, user_agent={}, request_url={}",
                            httpServletRequest.getRemoteHost(),  
                            httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT),
                            httpServletRequest.getRequestURL(), 
                            requestRejectedException
                    );

                httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
}
```

**STEP 4:** Add the custom filter to spring filter chain in security configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.addFilterBefore(new RequestRejectedExceptionFilter(),
             ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
}
```

Now using above fix, we can handle `RequestRejectedException` with Error 404  page.

Comment: Thank you. This is the approach I used temporarily to allow us to upgrade our Java microservice until the front-end apps are all upgraded. I didn't need step 3 and 4 to successfully allow '//' to be considered normalized. I just commented out the condition which checked for double-slash in isNormalized and then configured a bean to use the CustomStrictHttpFirewall class instead.

Comment: Is there an easier workaround via config ? But without turning off the firewall..

Answer (score 1):

this work for me :

```
@Bean
    public HttpFirewall looseHttpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowedHttpMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        firewall.setAllowBackSlash(true);
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedPercent(true);
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedPeriod(true);
        return firewall;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by not being logged in with Postman, so I opened a connection in another tab with a session cookie I took from the headers in my Chrome session.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i can use "setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true)":

```
@Bean
public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true);
    return firewall;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).