# "URL was not normalized" with Spring Boot 2 and Kotlin

Tags: apache, spring-boot, kotlin, openshift, spring-boot-actuator

In my current project we deploy several `Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE` microservices in `Openshift` with `Kubernetes`. We have configured an Apache Proxy Balancer:

```
From                            To
/msa/microname1          ->     /
/msa/microname2          ->     /
...
```

Recently we introduced `Spring Boot 2` and we developed a new microservice with `Kotlin`. We configured the balancer the same way considering that urls like `/health` and `/info` are placed under `/actuator` path.
Now when we consume any endpoint of this new microservice (`/health` or any of our endpoints) we are having an error like this:

> org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException:
>   The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized ...

The path that we intercept in our microservice has an extra slash in the beginning: `//<path_to_resource>`

When I use the microservice url I get the resource without problems, but when using the proxy balancer mapping we have the issue described above.

We checked our proxy balancer and it is configured the same way than the others.
Is is any extra configuration on `Spring Boot 2` we have to consider? 
Can this be a problem related to `Kotlin`?

**Update**

As a tweak we have configured the DefaultHttpFirewall to allow url enconded slash, but this does not fixes the issue with the double slash. It only masks the problem.

```
@Bean
fun allowUrlEncodedSlash(): HttpFirewall {
    var firewall: DefaultHttpFirewall = DefaultHttpFirewall()
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true)
    return firewall
}

override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
    web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlash())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding context to the application in our balancer.
Now all our endpoints have a context in our microservice, defined in application.yml.

```
From                            To
/msa/microname1          ->     /
/msa/microname2          ->     /
/msa/Kotlinname/kt       ->     /kt
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48644226/10451721

It seems to be the same issue as yours but in Java instead of Kotlin.

Spring doesn't like `//` in URLs by default.

I have converted the Java in the linked answer for you:

```
@Bean
fun allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall(): HttpFirewall {
    val firewall = StrictHttpFirewall()
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true)
    return firewall
}
```

Comment: Yes, we did the same yesterday but we are not confortable to modify the HttpFirewall. We are still looking for the root cause beacuse we don't add any extra bar.. At least that's what I think.