# The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized while deploying spring boot application in tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, url

I am facing following error while deploying Spring boot application in Tomcat

Error:- 
As i hit the following url
http://localhost:8080/serviceapp/

it is giving.

The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized

Unable to find the reason behind the above issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 5.0.3 RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453980/spring-5-0-3-requestrejectedexception-the-request-was-rejected-because-the-url)

Comment: I have checked that link. It does not help.

Comment: can you post the code related to how you defined your controller and the full exception with the stacktrace?